# Is it possible to modify an object's properties while simultaneously passing it to a method?

Tags: python, python-responses

I'm doing this:

```
response = responses.Response(
    url="www.google.com",
    method="POST",
    status=404,
)

response.body = requests.exceptions.ConnectionError()
responses.add(response)
```

That's fine but I would like to just do this:

```
responses.add(response.body=requests.exceptions.ConnectionError())
```

I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

So I have an instance of the Response class and I want to set a property on it *inside* of a function/method call. Is this just not possible? Is there a way to eval `responses.add(response.body=requests.exceptions.ConnectionError()` or something before handing it to add()?

I'm using the responses lib but I think this is also a more general Python question.

Comment: No, there's no way to do that. Perhaps you're thinking of JavaScript, where `responses.add({ ...response, body: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError() })` would work.

Comment: i suspected it was not possible, it was a hard google to confirm that though! The issue is that I can't use expressions inside function calls right? Is that the correct technical interpretation of whats happening here?

Comment: You can't use *statements* inside function calls; an *expression* would be fine.

Comment: @red888 no, you can use expressions just fine inside a function call. You can't use an assignment statement.

Comment: cool well ill accept an answer then explaining that, thanks! now I need to read up on python parlance around "statement" vs "expression"

Comment: Note, the actual answer to the question as stated in the title is "it depends". For example, an API can define a method that mutates an object and then returns the object. For exampled, `my_object.update_foo(42)` which updates some internal attribute and returns `my_object`, you could do something like `some_func(my_object.update_foo(42))`

Comment: @red888 Check out the glossary: [*expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-expression), and the grammar: [Assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)